# trying to understand table size

Tags: mysql, innodb

Can somebody help explain the "data_length" of the table? Why is it so big in my example below of a table with just one column and one row?

```
mysql> create table `network_type` ( `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into network_type(id) VALUES (1);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT data_length FROM information_schema.TABLES  WHERE table_schema = "test";

+-------------+
| data_length |
+-------------+
|       16384 |
+-------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: If you are using InnoDB, the default block size is 16KB, which is 16384 bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [**innodb_file_per_table**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_file_per_table) configured, the `network_type` table will exist in a physical file under the DB folder. For example, let's say your table has the following attributes:

- Table name `somedb.network_type`
- datadir is `/var/lib/mysql`

You will find the physical file `/var/lib/mysql/somedb/network_type.ibd`

That file is the home of all data and index pages in InnoDB. [The pre-compiled size of a page is 16K](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Innodb_page_size). There is room inside that page for more data, but 16K is the fixed allocation for data and index.

When you ran `SELECT data_length FROM information_schema.TABLES  WHERE table_schema = "test";`, MySQL simply reported the most granular space InnoDB is using.